# How to filter two lists of dict in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Forgive me if the topic allready exists, but I didn't find it...

I have 3 dict lists :

```py
list_1 = [
    {'name': "Leonardo Di Caprio", 'films': ["The revenant", "Titanic", "The wold of Wall Street"]},
    {'name': "Will Smith", 'films': ["I am a legend", "The pursuit of happyness"]},
    {'name': "Robert De Niro", 'films': ["Taxi driver", "The godfather"]}
]

list_2 = [
    {'name': "Leonardo Di Caprio", 'films': ["Titanic", "The revenant", "The wold of Wall Street"]},
    {'name': "Will Smith", 'films': ["I am a legend", "The pursuit of happyness", "Aladdin"]},
    {'name': "Robert De Niro", 'films': ["Taxi driver", "The godfather"]}
]

list_final = [
    {'name': "Tom Hanks", 'films': ["Forest Gump", "Cast Away", "Greyhound"]},
    {'name': "Will Smith", 'films': ["I am a legend", "The pursuit of happyness"]},
    {'name': "Tom Cruise", 'films': ["Top Gun", "Mission impossible"]},
    {'name': "Robert De Niro", 'films': ["Taxi driver", "The godfather"]},
    {'name': "Leonardo Di Caprio", 'films': ["Titanic", "The revenant", "The wold of Wall Street"]},
    {'name': "Harrison Ford", 'films': ["Blade Runner", "Indiana Jones"]},
    {'name': "Morgan Freeman", 'films': ["Seven"]}
]
```

I'd like to create a function that take 2 dict lists as paramaters and returns a boolean. The aim is to check if `list_1` is contained in `list_final`.
By "is contained" i mean :

- Every actor names froom `list_1` must be present in `list_final` (no matter the order)
- Every films played by a specific actor from `list_1` must be present in `list_final`

I have a functionnal code :

```py
def isContained(l1 : List[Dict[str, List]], l_final: List[Dict[str, List]]) -> bool:

    for elem in l1:
        findOccurence = False
        for element in l_final:
            if elem['name'] == element['name'] and all(item in element['films'] for item in elem['films']):
                findOccurence = True
        if not findOccurence:
            return False
    return True

print(isContained(list_1, list_final)) # True
print(isContained(list_2, list_final)) # False
print(isContained(list_1, list_2)) # True
print(isContained(list_2, list_1)) # False
```

Output :

```sh
root@root:/tmp/TEST_PYTHON$ python3 main.py
True
False
True
False
```

**So it works**, but I'm sure there is another way to code it in a more optimized algorithm.
What bothers me is iterating over the entire final list as many times as I have iterations on list_1

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Note that the word "functional" has [a very specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) in programming. I would avoid describing your code as "functional".

Comment: That's true, I wanted to say "working" code, thanks for the advice. Is it better ?

Answer (score 0):

After adjusting your data structures a little to make things a bit more efficient...

It can be done utilising the intersect operator `&` and issubset method on set.

```
list_1 = {
     "Leonardo Di Caprio":{"The revenant", "Titanic", "The wold of Wall Street"},
     "Will Smith":{"I am a legend", "The pursuit of happyness"},
     "Robert De Niro": {"Taxi driver", "The godfather"}
}

list_2 = {
    "Leonardo Di Caprio": {"Titanic", "The revenant", "The wold of Wall Street"},
    "Will Smith": {"I am a legend", "The pursuit of happyness", "Aladdin"},
    "Robert De Niro": {"Taxi driver", "The godfather"}
}

list_final = {
    "Tom Hanks": {"Forest Gump", "Cast Away", "Greyhound"},
    "Will Smith": {"I am a legend", "The pursuit of happyness"},
    "Tom Cruise": {"Top Gun", "Mission impossible"},
    "Robert De Niro": {"Taxi driver", "The godfather"},
    "Leonardo Di Caprio": {"Titanic", "The revenant", "The wold of Wall Street"},
    "Harrison Ford": {"Blade Runner", "Indiana Jones"},
    "Morgan Freeman": {"Seven"}
}


def isContained(l1, l_final) -> bool:
    if (set(l1.keys()).issubset(set(l1.keys()))):
        for key in set(l1.keys()) & set(l_final.keys()):
            if (not (l1[key].issubset(l_final[key]))):
                return False;
    return True;
```

After comments from @Stef solution has been fixed and is now:

```
def isContained(l1, l_final) -> bool:
    if (set(l1.keys()).issubset(set(l_final.keys()))):
        for key in set(l1.keys()) & set(l_final.keys()):
            if (not (l1[key].issubset(l_final[key]))):
                return False;
    else:
        return False
    return True;
```

An extra test condition is required to confirm the first condition is being met correctly...

```
list_3 = {"Sigourney Weaver": {"Aliens"}}
```

And condition:

```
print(isContained(list_3, list_final)) # False
```

Comment: `set(l1.keys()).issubset(set(l1.keys()))` I think one of those should be `l_final` rather than `l1`?

Comment: There is also another mistake - if the condition of the outer `if` is false, then `isContained` returns `True`. But it should return `False` in that case, right?

Comment: You could rewrite the whole thing as `def isContained(l1, l2): return (set(l1.keys()).issubset(l2.keys())) and all(set(v).issubset(l2[k]) for k,v in l1.items())`

Comment: You could also complete your answer by providing a function to convert the OP's list format to your dict format: `def dict_of_list(l): return {x['name']: set(x['films']) for x in l}`

Comment: I don't see the point of the intersection operator `&` in the for-loop; at this point you've already checked that `l1.keys()` was a subset of `l_final.keys()`, so it follows that `set(l1.keys()) & set(l_final.keys()) == set(l1.keys())`.

Comment: @Stef thanks for all this comments.

Comment: Thanks @Stef for your input!
1. if (set(l1.keys()).issubset(set(l1.keys()))): is indeed incorrect. Reason it "passes" is because the test conditions are not enough. No test actually tests that l1 is indeed a subset of l_final.
2. set(l1.keys()) & set(l_final.keys()) is not equal to set(l1.keys()) as there could be keys in l1 that are _not_ in l_final and they would not be in the intersection of the two sets.

Comment: *"there could be keys in l1 that are not in l_final and they would not be in the intersection of the two sets."* But that's not true. That's my point. This code condition is tested inside the body of `if (set(l1.keys()).issubset(set(l_final.keys()))):`. So at this point, there cannot be any keys that are in `l1` but not in `l_final`.

Comment: @stef {1,2} & {2,3} = {2} - thus there is an element in set1 (1) that is not in set 2...

Comment: @MichaelWiles Yes. And accordingly `{1,2}.issubset({2,3})` will return `False`.